# Freemarker method cannot accept object as parameters

Tags: java, freemarker

I am trying to pass Freemarker HashLiteral to my custom method as follows:

```
<a href="${href("Item", {"item": item})}">...</a>
```

where item without quotes is an object given in ModelAndView. The `{"item": item}` is correctly transformed to `freemarker.core.HashLiteral$SequenceHash`, but I cannot recover it in my method as I get following exception:

```
Expecting a string, date or number here, 
   Expression {"item": item} is instead a freemarker.core.HashLiteral$SequenceHash
```

This happens even with `href` method having empty body:

```
public TemplateModel exec(List args) throws TemplateModelException {
    return new SimpleScalar("");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How does the definition of the `href` method look like?

Comment: I've added the href method to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably that `href` is a `TemplateMethodModel` instead of a `TemplateMethodModelEx`. The `args` argument in `TemplateMethodModel.exec(args)` is a `List` of `String`-s, hence FreeMarker tries to convert the value to a string, but it can only do that with string, date or number values. So just change it to `TemplateMethodModelEx` and then `args` will be a `List` of `TemplateModel`-s and hence accepts all kind of values.